# How can I make this logo look more obviously like an icing bag and a crown?

Tags: logo, icon, critique, branding

For my brand identity class, I had to do a logo for a local bakery.
**The first one is what I started with. The bottom is where I am now**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**The problem I'm having:** I need to show lines or shapes indicating grooves in the icing bag because right now it's not reading an "icing bag" & a crown, more so a carrot and a crown. All of the options I've explored thus far don't flow with the overall shape. Because of this not being resolved, I haven't been able to really explore the type portion so don't mind the type.

How can I make this logo look more obviously like an icing bag and crown?

Comment: Is it totally impossible to have the business name as the output of the icing bag? There are plenty of rich enough script fonts for it. Have the bag a little tilted and connected to the last frill.

Comment: I've gone that route earlier in this process but I think I'm gonna revisit that idea.

Comment: @user287001 I don't see how that will improve visibility and recognizability. Plus "Elite Customs" screams regal and proper. If you have the text being piped out it would lose that and might become too playful. See example: https://logopond.com/logos/ed6f8d583cc516f7cd21d818b215fdd7.png

Comment: @user287001 Mixing type like that sounds bad. Plus the type should be the ** the last thing** that should be considered when the form itself isn't nailed down. Ignore color > nail down form > experiment with type > compromise form > final solution

Comment: Yeah from top (top being the worst) to bottom is some of what I explored, I've strayed from the two font idea. The bottom one is where I am now.

Comment: @BrianaSmith the top 2 are the best options. Explore from there. Also, not sure what vector you cut apart to make this but the bottom is pretty off. https://imgur.com/a/ILeWw6t

Comment: Yeah I preferred to fix that one too but my professor said I was making it too complicated which is why I stopped trying to resolve that one but okay.

Comment: @BrianaSmith Simplier is not always better. If he's saying that try reducing the size and number of cut outs in the crown.

Comment: You are restricting your problem to "I need to show lines or shapes indicating grooves in the icing bag" when you would have more options if you only considered "it's not reading an "icing bag" & a crown". You say in a comment below that you have to implement the crown to show "Elite", is that part of the agreement with your teacher or can you use other symbols that could effectively represent the "elite" quality?

Comment: Yes we settled on these two ideas merging so unfortunately I'm stuck making these two work. :(

Comment: Hi Briana. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. I made some edits to focus the question a bit, feel free to [edit] again. Please have a peek at our [guidelines for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682) if you haven't already. Thanks!

Comment: Where's the cake?  I'd say it needs an outline of a cake to associate the icing bag with the word Cakes in the name.

Comment: Why do you need the whole icing bag? Perhaps the piping tip could be the crown, some of these decorating tips have sort of a crown shape http://simplytale.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Star-tips-ST.jpg

Comment: I personally still gravitate toward the original green ones at the top of this question over all of the answers. i do like user287001's answer, it looks nice as well.

Comment: I like your original in bold. Simplifying a design does not always add.

Answer (score 52):

An answer: The bag should output something - the text or something else in a cake. Let the business name be the biggest element.

[image]

Comment: These are brilliant designs--but be aware that there are a lot of cake-eaters (and cake-buyers) that don't know, or care, how a cake is made, and wouldn't recognize an icing bag if we saw one in the baker's hands!

Comment: @CCTO That's a really good point, and a common mistake of designing a logo that is meaningful to the business owners.  Design it to be meaningful to the **customers**.

Answer (score 18):

Just to address the icon part of this, building on existing answers and adding a few things. I think the devil is in the details here. Quick blown-up sketch (n.b. the ratio of tip/bag is currently not ideal to represent a piping bag but not too bad for a logo which would have to be legible at small sizes):

[image]

You want to keep the small details that make the piping bag not look like a carrot. Working from bottom to top:

- Build a metallic reflection on the tip and remove the horizontal lines which are often seen on cartoonish or schematized carrots
- Keep the little bulge you already had on your first two proposals
- Give the bag a lumpier shape and add some lines to show dimension
- Adding a knot or twist or something that suggests a grip (without adding a full size hand) also distances this from being a carrot
- Consistency requires we would also had some lines in the crown (which would not appear in a carrot's leaves but would in a bag)
- Removing a few tips from the crown can also make your design relate more to a bag and less like carrot leaves. Making the points not too stiff also drives the connection to reading "bag"
- Consider your choice of color (I'm not sure if you've mentioned the # of inks you can use for this): keep away from anything orangey looking for the bottom of the design and stick to something golden/silver-ish for the top. That color could easily be repeated on the metallic tip to give a better unity to your design.
- Consider building metallic reflections on some parts of the crown if fitting.
- I did not address the type component but I think you had a good lead in your first proposals of using the bag to put the dot on the i of Elite (as opposed to piping out the whole brand name which becomes complicated and removes a bit of the glamour you are aiming for). Conveniently, the "i" is right in the middle of the word so you could definitely implement this all the while keeping the symmetry of your design. Keeping the same really straight font you are using in the bottom proposals but adding a dab of icing as a dot would offer some contrast and create more meaning.

Comment: That was really helpful thank you!! And I can only have two spot colors.

Comment: I think you can definitely pull this off with two colors :) I'll be happy to answer further if you come back to your question with updated work. Best of luck!

Answer (score 10):

My first impression was not a carrot but a big misil bomb falling on the extensive typographical horizon.

[image: bomb]

- I guess the color is distracting you in the development of the design. Design in black and white helps to understand the formal language.
- It is true what Welz shows that the verticality is no the natural position of an icing bag.
- On the other side, the typography is proposed as an entity completely separated from the image, this accentuates the pump-carrot
- It would be interesting to integrate the image and its immediate action into the design.

[image]

[image: cake]

Comment: I particularly like the ones where the icing bag is crossing the 't'.

Comment: To be exact, and fully agreeing to your point, it looks neither like a missile nor a bomb - it looks like a mortar round!

Answer (score 4):

Your main issues are the angles you picked for the crown and the shape of the bag.

I get you want to use nice lines but you are making the mistake of trying to make an organically shaped object geometrically rigid.

If you make the bag more "lumpy" and have more curves this will help break up the harsh angles and lines. I've also added some "cut-outs" that mimic the scrunched top of the bag when it's full and twisted closed.

[image]
Second I would make the crown more proportional to the rest of the bag. You have a VERY large and extending footprint which throws off the balance of the rest of the bag. Making it narrower and more "crown-like" will help immensely.

Something like this is a good start.

[image]

### Here's a final "concept" to further illustrate my point.

[image]

Second iteration showing how you could emphasize the crown and altering the proportions.

[image]

---

I think you need to refine your shape and then reassess the feel of the branding first. You seem to have conflicting ideas on your direction. Ignore the color altogether, start in black and white and get your shapes down **first**, THEN you can start playing around with color.

Comment: Sorry - I just added the same thing to my own answer - it was actually an independent thought, though it does heavily echo yours.

Comment: @Tetsujin No worries, it's the most logical step to take to mimic the bag.

Comment: Hmm. I instantly recognized the ones in the question as piping bags but I'm not sure I recognize yours. :-( (Though, of course, your main point is the technique, rather than the result.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Exactly, I'm not here to give the final result just guide in the processes.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding in a little squirt of icing on the bottom:

[image]

I then applied a little shear to the icing

[image]

You can also try to rotate it around 45°, it makes it seem less like a carrot.
[image]

Comment: First thing is that looks like a 3D printer's extruder, secondly the 45° just introduces a lot of disproportional negative space. Altering the angles and proportions are the way to solve this, not introducing more visual variables.

Answer (score 2):

just a 2 minute tweak...

Anything wrong with breaking up the angle at the top?
How about 'jaunty'...

[image]

Or fatten the sides of the bag a bit; less rigid.

[image]

...quickly [& not very accurately] done in Ps using cut/paste for the crown, then free Transform.
Baggy sides using Liquify.

If you have only a solid single colour to work with, ie no shading, then add some 'bag squeeze' perhaps...

[image]

Comment: The crown isn't the issue as she stated. The bag doesn't look like a piping bag.

Comment: Actually, the crown makes the carrot top; that's where psychology takes over. Remove the crown, it looks nothing like a carrot. tbh, it looks like an amphora whichever way you do it ;)

Comment: I have to implement a crown in to show "Elite"/ I already told my professor the icing bag and the crown are the two objects I'd merge with one another. For that double read effect I placed them the way I did.... I just need to figure out how to make the bag look like an icing bag :,(

Comment: Are you stuck with a solid single-colour? If so, tweak added...

Comment: I can have two spot colors. The only color combos I've explored were prink & brown / teal and white / mint green and brown.

Comment: @BrianaSmith I'd stay away with browns. Also, I'm not sold on thinking elite when you have this salmon color.

Comment: Its gotta be playful to some degree right though, it is a bakery? http://elitecustomcakes.business.site/

Comment: @BrianaSmith Design in black and white then work on color. Based on their shop I'd try some pastel blues/teals. But design first color last.

Comment: That site looked very 'American', not at all what you'd think of Norfolk... took me a minute to realise *that* Norfolk is in the US... another 'borrow' from UK geography ;)

Comment: If you angle the bag, but keep the crown upright, the crown would look less like part of the bag (you could show a twisted top to the bag, with the crown on the bulge).

Answer (score 1):

It's not reading "icing bag" because there's no hand squeezing it.  Include a hand (and maybe a wrist, or at least some fingers) squeezing the bag, and people will get it.  I'd drop the crown; it just makes the bag too big (it's too big even without the crown).

Answer (score 1):

I think the darker border and lighter fill that were on the initial designs really helped sell the idea that these were transparent bags with something inside, rather than opaque, solid objects. Perhaps reintroducing the border, with or without the fill, would help. If you do end up doing that, you should keep the crown solid for contrast; I think it would probably also be best to keep it closer to the border color rather than the fill color, but that would probably be subject to how it looks when implemented.

Answer (score 1):

By going back to your initial concept, where the bag was doing the writing.  The more you move away from this concept, the more it looks like a bomb.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is trying to make the crown work visually with the icing bag, when you would never see a crown where you a putting it. So not only are you fighting the visual simplification of the elements, the stylization, you are also fighting logic.

The crown is a requirement but does it have to be part of the icing bag? If it were me, I would have the icing bag drawing the crown which the Elite type is wearing. That shows the Elite company is king (not the bag) which is on brand and it eliminates the problem of integrating two otherwise unrelated objects.